# What are toxins?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, poison

The spell [Restoration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=258) says:

> When you cast restoration, choose to either reduce a condition or **lessen the effect of a toxin**.

It references "toxin" many times more. But, what is a toxin? It's clearly some sort of [affliction](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=361), but it doesn't seem to be a defined term anywhere I could find, and I'm fairly familiar with the rules for PF2e. I'm guessing it's just a typo (or result of a last-minute terminology change; there are a few of those in the CRB). But, what is a toxin? Am I missing something? Is there a reasonable inference as to a meaning?

Answer (score 9):

### All poisons are toxins, not all toxins are poisons

The terms toxin, poison, and venom are used interchangeably but they have subtly different meanings.

A poison is a toxin that is ingested, inhaled, or absorbed. A venom is a toxin that is injected. Toadstools are poisonous, snakes are venomous; both are toxic.

AFAIK, pathfinder uses poison when they should actually use toxin. Except here for some reason.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, but the casting time of Restoration makes it useless against many poisons in that case. And then there's the case of the feat [Absorb Toxin](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2826) which references poisons and diseases. IRL, yes, you're definitions are correct, but it seems PF2e isn't using IRL definitions for this.

Answer (score 3):

### Toxins=Poisons....probably.

A search on the Archives of Nethys for [toxins](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=toxin) yields 152 results.  A scan of various things with toxin in its name clearly indicates that [they are hazards](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=681).  Examples with toxins in their name seem to all reference poisons. For example, [here](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=649) it shows that you can turn toxins from the frog into poison,  [poison resistance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=96) specifically says your body "becomes fortified against toxins".  [belladonna](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=105) is called a toxin in the flavor text.

From context, it seems pretty clear that they mean toxins=poisons, but forgot to actually explicitly say that. I can't find anything in my quick skimming of the search results that say otherwise

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, but the casting time of Restoration makes it useless against many poisons in that case. And then there's the case of the feat [Absorb Toxin](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2826) which references poisons and diseases. IRL, yes, you're definitions are correct, but it seems PF2e isn't using IRL definitions for this. (Same comment as on Dale M's answer)